# Use Mixin property in a Controller

Tags: ember.js

This is a crappy example, but I am merely trying to use a mixin's property in a controller. I did the same thing in a route and could access that property. I've tried every way to reference a property I know... What am I misunderstanding?

```
// app/mixins/author-data.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  authorName: 'Example author name',
});
```

```
// app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthorDatas from 'app-name/mixins/author-data';

export default Ember.Controller.extend(AuthorDatas, {

  siteTitle: `Site title`,   

  fromAuthorData: this.get('authorName'), 
  // returns  - what is the proper syntax?

  actions: {
    showAuthor() {
      var author = this.get('fromAuthorData');
      console.log(`Author from controller: ${author}`);
    },
  },

});
```

```
// app/templates/application.hbs
{{fromAuthorData}}
```

This works...

```
// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthorDatas from 'app-name/mixins/author-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthorDatas, {

  afterModel() { // arbitrary
    var intro = `Author from route:`;
    console.log(`${intro} this.authorName`, this.authorName );
    console.log(`${intro} this.get('author-name')`, this.get('authorName') );
  },

});
```

(I would have made an ember-twiddle - but I wasn't sure if Mixins would work the same way ~ since they aren't on the list and there is 0 documentation)

Comment: `fromAuthorData` in your example is literally a pile of poo, can you replace this with the source code?

Comment: just imagine `this.get('authorName')` is there

Comment: I guess, In ember-twiddle everything will just work, for mixins you need create file like `mixins/author-data.js`

Answer (score 0):

The `fromAuthorData` property on your controller should be defined like this (I think):

```
fromAuthorData: Ember.computed('authorName', function() {
  return this.get('authorName'); // or whatever derived value you need
}
```

Comment: Why? If the mixin just adds in the properties, why wouldn't it just be the same as `siteTitle: "My App",`

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem we need to talk about scope, when you extend/create an object you are merely passing in options, your code is no different than:

```
let options = {

  siteTitle: `Site title`, 

  // `this` is undefined since we are in strict mode
  fromAuthorData: this.get('authorName'),

  actions: {
    showAuthor() {
      var author = this.get('fromAuthorData');
      console.log(`Author from controller: ${author}`);
    },
  }
};

export default Ember.Controller.extend(AuthorDatas, options);
```

Now to access properties that rely on `this` being the object holding it you will need a function that is run with the object as it's context that returns that value, enter [computed properties](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/object-model/computed-properties/).
Your code becomes:

```
// app/controllers/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthorDatas from 'app-name/mixins/author-data';

const { computed } = Ember; 

export default Ember.Controller.extend(AuthorDatas, {
  siteTitle: `Site title`,   

  // We add `authorName` as the dependent key, should it change `fromAuthorData` will update
  fromAuthorData: computed('authorName', function() {
    // your author data stuff
    let authorName = this.get('authorName');
    // ...
    return authorDetails;
  }), 

  actions: {
    showAuthor() {
      var author = this.get('fromAuthorData');
      console.log(`Author from controller: ${author}`);
    },
  },
});
```